# How do I paint over unpaintable silicone?

Tags: paint, silicone

So I stupidly used unpaintable silicone to seal my bedroom window... On the inside. How can I paint over this unpaintable silicone? (GE brand).

Comment: A little more information about the caulk application, please. Perhaps a photo.

Comment: @Isherwood thin bead in inside corners up sides of window where it contacts drywall.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Paint over it (or to either side) and ignore the strip where the paint won't stick.

Pull it out and re-caulk with something paintable.

Try to smear paintable silicone over the top of it and hope that sticks to the stuff you have. *Hard to do neatly, pulling it out and redoing is more likely to succeed, IMHO.*

Comment: Thanks. The more I think about it, the more obvious the answer is: sand / rip it out and redo. Will take 30 minutes tops.

Answer (score -3):

You could try sanding it with 1000 or 1500 very fine grit. The paint will then probably 'take hold'